# JavaScript loop using set amount of steps while skipping specific step

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to create a loop that allows you to go up in increments of one each time using "x" amount of steps while skipping a specific step.  example 1 would be you have 2 actions and need to skip step 2.  so you would go from 0 to 1 and then 1 to 3.  example 2 would be you have 3 actions and need to skip step 3 so you could either go from 0 to 1, wait 1 round, then go from 1 to 4 since you would be skipping up two.  or you could wait at 0 then skip to 2 and then skip to 5.

i know I am close using a while loop with continue but it doesn't quite work like expected.

```
function maxStep(n, k) {
    let step = n
    let bad = k
    let total = 0
    while (total <= step) {
        total += 1
        if (total === bad) {
            continue;
        }
        total += 1
        return total
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please describe it with input and expected output

Comment: return in while loop so the while run only one time

Comment: I understood the question fine.

Comment: As far as I understand your question, in example 2, you have 3 actions each round. So from step 0, in one round, you can either: - Spend 1 action to "jump" to step 1 (not skip any step) - Spend 2 actions to "jump" to step 2 (skip step 1) - Spend 3 actions to "jump" to step 3 (skip steps 1 and 2) The condition is go to the end and don't stop at step 3. So what number do you want, number of actions or number of rounds you have spent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome @jaronow!

First, `continue` skips you to the next iteration of the `while`. So what you've written here...

```
if (total === bad) {
    continue;
}
total += 1
```

...actually means, *"If this is a bad number of steps, then skip adding 1."* But you mean the opposite, don't you?

```
if (total === bad) {
    total += 1
}
```

This now says, *"If this is a bad number of steps, add another 1."* There, so now we have

```
function maxStep(n, k) {
    let step = n
    let bad = k
    let total = 0
    while (total <= step) {
        total += 1
        if (total === bad) {
            total += 1 // Put this here instead of continue.
        }
        return total
    }
}
```

Now, where you put this is odd:

```
return total
```

This actually exits the entire function the first time it's encountered. Surely you mean to calculate `total` by running through your loop as many times as needed, then return the result at the *end*, like this:

```
function maxStep(n, k) {
    let step = n
    let bad = k
    let total = 0
    while (total <= step) {
        total += 1
        if (total === bad) {
            total += 1
        }
    }
    return total // Moved this out.
}
```

Finally, there's two subtle issues (noticed the second one later). First, if you take that "extra step" because you've encountered a bad step, you need to increase `step` as well, since it's the maximum number of steps you plan to take. But also, once you reach that number of steps, you don't want to enter the loop again and add *another* to `total`, so you need to use `<` instead of `<=`. (You'll find it a common pattern in programming that when you intend to do things N times, you write your loops saying `< N`, not `<= N`.)

```
function maxStep(n, k) {
    let step = n
    let bad = k
    let total = 0
    while (total < step) {
        total += 1
        if (total === bad) {
            total += 1
            step += 1 // Add this.
        }
    }
    return total
}
```

Otherwise, your `total` will always end up at the original number of `step`s.

There are other shorter, possibly more clever ways of solving this problem, but I'm aiming to teach by sticking to your formulation.

---

Not something you have to care about, but in case you want to see, a seasoned programmer may "refactor" your code this way:

```
function getStepsTaken(desiredStepsToTake, badNumberOfSteps) {
    let stepsToTake = desiredStepsToTake
    // let bad = k (don't need this line)
    let stepsTaken = 0
    while (stepsTaken < stepsToTake) {
        stepsTaken += 1
        if (stepsTaken === badNumberOfSteps) {
            stepsTaken += 1
            stepsToTake += 1
        }
    }
    return stepsTaken
}
```

You may find it ugly, and indeed it's much more verbose, but it's always better to make things very clear, even if just for yourself and you rename the variables later.

Solid attempt though, keep it up.

Comment: Noticed that `<=` should also be `<` and edited my answer.

Comment: thank you very much for clearing that up.  I am currently just starting out learning and a loop of this level was never in the courses I took and have been stumped for a day trying things.  Your explanation really helps me grasp loops and what you can do with them now.